# Update location.search in component as updating the url params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to show the search parameters in the `Second` component in which I am accessing the search parameters, which are updated from `First Component` but in the `Second` component, `location.search` parameters are not updating as the param changes.

```
function FirstComponent() {
  const [searchBlogName, setSearchBlogName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    if (searchBlogName) {
      params.set('q', searchBlogName);
    }
    const blogNameString = params.toString();
    window.history.replaceState({}, '', blogNameString ? `?${blogNameString}` : window.location.pathname);
  }, [searchBlogName])

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => setSearchBlogName(e.target.value)}
    />
  )
}
```

```
function SecondComponent() {
  const location = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.search);
  }, [location.search]);

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

When I attempt to print the parameters in the `Second` component, they do not display correctly due to continuous changes in the parameters.

I have tried using `useMemo` like

```js
useMemo(() => {
  console.log(location.search)
}, [location]);
```

It is not showing either.

Then I tried creating a custom hook like

```
const useReactPath = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [path, setPath] = useState(location.search);
  const listenToPopstate = () => {
    const winPath = location.search;
    setPath(winPath);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", listenToPopstate);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", listenToPopstate);
    };
  }, []);
  return path;
};
```

However, it didn't work, and it's not printing anything as the parameter changes.

How can I access the params as they change in the `Second` Component?

Comment: How exactly do these two components relate to each other? What routing library are you using? React-Router? The code appears to be mutating a separate history object than that what the `useLocation` hook would reference. Please [edit] to clarify the problem and to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: They don't. I am accessing the params directly without any component relation to each other. It's like One is setting params and another is accessing params

Comment: That makes no sense. If these are completely unrelated components then it is entirely unclear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I just want to access the params in `Second component` to trigger a function when the params update

Comment: Then trigger the second component to rerender somehow so it reads the `location.search` value. Are these two components being rendered at the same time?

Comment: @DrewReese One is permanent on screen and second is Route component.

Comment: Do you mind adding your router, routes and routed components to your post? I think I understand more now what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are updating the global `window.history` object reference in the first component, but using the `useLocation` hook in the second which only references the internal `history` reference the `react-router-dom` router component maintains. In other words, the actions done in `FirstComponent` are not made aware to the routing context that `SecondComponent` is consuming.

## Solution

`FirstComponent` should effect a navigation action via the routing context such that `SecondComponent` will be triggered to be rerendered and pick up the updated `location.search` value.

Here's a trivial example using the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook in `FirstComponent` to update *just* the search string. The navigation action will be effected and `SecondComponent` is rerendered and reads `location.search`.

Example Code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useLocation, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

function FirstComponent() {
  const [, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const [searchBlogName, setSearchBlogName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the search string and "navigate"
    if (searchBlogName) {
      setSearchParams({ q: searchBlogName }, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [searchBlogName, setSearchParams]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>FirstComponent</h1>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setSearchBlogName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function SecondComponent() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("SecondComponent", location.search);
  }, [location.search]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>SecondComponent</h1>
      <div>Search: {location.search}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FirstComponent />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SecondComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit update-location-search-in-component-as-updating-the-url-params]

[image]